# One huge GraphQl query for all page components instead of multiple single queries - what about navigation and already loaded data?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, relayjs, hotchocolate

Imagine a main page at url path `/` with components `ComponentA`, `ComponentB` and `ComponentMain`. So maybe something like this:

[image]

Instead of `ComponentA`, `ComponentB` and `ComponentMain` *each* making a single GraphQl query on their own, one could hoist up the state and then make one huge query and pass down the needed data to each component. All fine with that. But imagine a user navigates and the content of `ComponentMain` changes. There are two different ways of navigating:

1. User is already on `/` and clicks some link which changes the content of `MainComponent`. In that case the data for `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` is already available from the user's initial call to `/`. I only want to load the data for `MainComponent`, not again the data for `ComponentA` and `ComponentB`.
2. User is not already on the page, but directly uses a link like `/someOtherMainContent`. In that case, the data for `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` isn't loaded yet. All data (`ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, `ComponentMain`) needs to be loaded.

I could code all that logic manually from ground up, but that would be very cumbersome. Is `relayjs` capable of exactly doing such things? Is that possible with `Apollo Client`? Is there any pattern for this?

I am using React via NextJs 13 and a GraphQl backend (currently independent from NextJs, coded using ASP.Net Core and HotChocolate GraphQl server).

Answer (score 1):

If `ComponentMain` is a fragment created with `useFragment`, change it to `useRefetchableFragment` that will allow you to refetch changing the variables.

If the fragment (or its selection set) is different different in each deep link, then it becomes more complex.

Something like this might work as explained above:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { graphql, useRelayEnvironment, useLazyLoadQuery, useRefetchableFragment, useFragment } from 'react-relay';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const environment = useRelayEnvironment();
  const [selectedItemId, setSelectedItemId] = useState(null);

  const data = useLazyLoadQuery(
    graphql`
      query MyComponentQuery($itemId: ID!) {
        sidePanelData {
          ...SidePanel_data
        }
        mainPanelData: mainPanelDataQuery(itemId: $itemId) {
          ...MainPanel_data
        }
      }
    `,
    { itemId: selectedItemId },
    { fetchPolicy: 'store-or-network' }
  );

  const sidePanelData = useFragment(
    graphql`
      fragment SidePanel_data on SidePanelData {
        # side panel fields
      }
    `,
    data.sidePanelData
  );

  const { data: mainPanelData, refetch: refetchMainPanel } = useRefetchableFragment(
    graphql`
      fragment MainPanel_data on MainPanelData
      @refetchable(queryName: "MainPanelRefetchQuery") {
        # main panel fields
      }
    `,
    data.mainPanelData
  );

  const handleLinkClick = (itemId) => {
    setSelectedItemId(itemId);
    refetchMainPanel({ itemId });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SidePanel data={sidePanelData} />
      <MainPanel data={mainPanelData} onLinkClick={handleLinkClick} />
    </>
  );
};

const SidePanel = ({ data }) => {
  // Render side panel using data
};

const MainPanel = ({ data, onLinkClick }) => {
  // Render main panel using data
  const handleLinkClick = (itemId) => {
    onLinkClick(itemId);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render main panel content */}
      <button onClick={() => handleLinkClick(itemId)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```